# How to get a random key-value pair from dictionary where there are many values to one key?

Tags: python, tuples

I'm trying to use random.sample() to return a random key-value pair, and print just the key, i.e fruits: papaya, but my code return a TypeError. How to fix it? Thanks!

```
import random

Dictionary = {"fruits": ["watermelon","papaya", "apple"], "buildings": ["apartment", "museum"], "mammal": ["horse", "giraffe"], "occupation": ["fireman", "doctor"]}


def choose_word():
    hint, chosen_word = random.sample(Dictionary.items(), 2)
    print("Hint: " + hint)
    blank = []
    for letter in chosen_word:
        blank.append("_")
    print("".join(blank))
    return chosen_word
```

Error message

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str
```

Comment: Your description doesn't match your code: Do you want to return the key (e.g. `fruits`) or the value, joined by `_`, e.g. `"watermelon_papaya_apple"`?

Comment: @mcsoini I just want to have one value with its key. The key is to be printed and its value replaced by `_`. I edited my question for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

`random.sample(Dictionary.items(), 2)` returns two random key-value pairs from the dictionary, so `hint` becomes your first key-value pair, and `chosen_word` the second one. Therefore, hint is `('fruits', ['watermelon', 'papaya', 'apple'])`. Since you can't concatenate a string (`"Hint: "`) and a tuple (`hint`), you get that error.

Do you only want a single key-value pair? Do `hint, chosen_word = random.sample(Dictionary.items(), 1)[0]`

If you want to print a string of underscores with one underscore per word  in the key, simply do: `print("_" * len(chosen_word))`

So, overall:

```
import random

Dictionary = {"fruits": ["watermelon","papaya", "apple"], 
              "buildings": ["apartment", "museum"], 
              "mammal": ["horse", "giraffe"], 
              "occupation": ["fireman", "doctor"]}

def choose_word():
    hint, chosen_word = random.sample(Dictionary.items(), 1)[0]
    print("Hint: " + hint)      
    print("_" * len(chosen_word))
    return chosen_word

choose_word()
```

Prints:

```
Hint: mammal
__
```

Returns:

```
Out[2]: ['horse', 'giraffe']
```

Comment: yes that's what I want. What does `[0]` mean?

Comment: `random.sample(Dictionary.items(), 1)` gives a list of key-value pairs with length 1. Since you want to obtain the key-value pair itself, you need to select the first (and only) element of the list.

Comment: @Kentta see the updated answer for more simplifications

Comment: the code return just two letters of the value when I run it, although the first print statement is alright.

Comment: @Kentta I don't understand. See the updated answer for the output you  get with this code.

Comment: my desired output is Hint: mammal _ _ _ _ _ (supposed it's 'horse') . But the output is just Hint: (key) and _ _ .

Comment: @Kentta try this: `"_".join(max([len(i) for i in chosen_word]))`

Comment: But for a random key you still have list. Do you also want to select a random animal?

Comment: @Yogaraj `"_".join(max([len...` would never make sense since `"_".join(...)` requires an iterable, not an int

Comment: My mistake.. It should be `"_"*(max([len(i) for i in chosen_word]))`

Comment: @Yogaraj You are assuming they want the longest word, which is baseless.

Answer (score 1):

As per the docs of [random.sample](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample), it will return a list of unique elements chosen from the population sequence or set.

In your sample code, `random.sample(Dictionary.items(), 2)` will return a list with a length of 2.

```
In [1]: random.sample(Dictionary.items(), 2)                                                                                                                                                  
Out[1]: [('occupation', ['fireman', 'doctor']), ('mammal', ['horse', 'giraffe'])]
```

You need to change the argument for `random.sample` method from 2 to 1 and while expanding,

```
hint, chosen_word = random.sample(Dictionary.items(), 1)[0]
```

`hint` contains the key and `chosen_word` will contain list of values.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution after referencing @Yogaraj and @mcsoini

```
import random


Dictionary = {"fruits": ["watermelon", "papaya", "apple"],
              "buildings": ["apartment", "museum"],
              "mammal": ["horse", "giraffe"],
              "occupation": ["fireman", "doctor"]}


def choose_word():
    hint, chosen_words = random.choice(list(Dictionary.items()))
    print("Hint: " + hint)
    chosen_word = random.choice(list(chosen_words))
    print("_" * len(chosen_word))
    return chosen_word
```

It is a bit long, but it manages to avoid using random.sample() because it is being deprecated anyway.